# Neo4j ProcedureException : Procedures with zero output fields must be declared as VOID

Tags: java, plugins, neo4j

I was using a custom procedure with Neo4j enterprise-3.0.4 and it was working fine over there.But recently I switched to the latest version i.e Neo4j enterprise-3.2.1. when I try to start the serverwith the custom procedure as plugin it it throwing the below exception:

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.Procedures@3018c593' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Procedures with zero output fields must be declared as VOID".
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:444)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:205)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.ProcedureException: Procedures with zero output fields must be declared as VOID
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ProcedureRegistry.register(ProcedureRegistry.java:64)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.Procedures.register(Procedures.java:123)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.Procedures.register(Procedures.java:78)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.Procedures.start(Procedures.java:278)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
    ... 11 more
```

Please let me know why I am getting this error with the latest version where-as in docs its mentioned that any plugins after 3.x will work in 3.2.x version of neo4j.

Comment: show some code please

Comment: could be that you are CALLing some Apoc procedures that moved to the neo4j packages too.

Comment: I don't have the code. I am using the jar file of the plugin.

Comment: What plugin are you using?

Comment: custom procedure plugin

Comment: The code has to be available in your org. 
Ask your manager

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem when using to return a stream of built-in type Node in my procedure. To address this problem, I only create a new class to handle it.

```
    public class NewNodeClass{
       public final Node newNodeObject;

       public Hashtag(Node node) { this.newNodeObject = node;}
    }
```